# GPS measured codephase error correction due to acceleration

Tags: parameter-estimation, gps, gnss

If GPS L1C/A receiver is experiencing a Doppler shift of $f_D$ and a Doppler rate of $\alpha_D$, assuming total integration duration of $T_{int}$, then how should I calculate the code phase estimate error due to this changing Doppler shift effect?
I understand that the code rate will change by a factor of : $$R_c\prime(t) = R_c.(1 + \frac{f_D}{f_C} + \frac{\alpha_D}{f_C}t)$$. What would be the impact of this time varying code rate when we correlate and integrate longer duration codes? Also if the total duration of integration is divided into coherent and non-coherent integrations, then should the impact be handled differently?

Comment: Could you define some of your terms and variables a little more? Not everyone here is a GPS expert, but some might still have insight to offer.